# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is in expression '{!authorize}' in component

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to connect to a REST API https://www.gliffy.com/products/online/api/apidocs/rest/ using oAuth in salesforce

Not sure why i am getting this error, is it SSL issue or code error

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!authorize}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page oauthplayground:authpage: (oauthplayground)

An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (oauthplayground)
```

**My Controller looks like this**

```
public with sharing class AuthController {

    public String service { get; set; }

    public String authUrl { get; set; }

    public boolean authSuccess { get; set; }

    public String message { get; set; }

    public List<SelectOption> services {
        get {
            if(services==null) {
                List<OAuthService__c> l = [SELECT name FROM OAuthService__c];
                services = new List<SelectOption>();
                for(OAuthService__c obj : l) {
                    services.add(new SelectOption(obj.name,obj.name));
                    System.debug('service: '+obj.name);
                }
            }
            return services;
        }
        set;
    }

    public PageReference authorize() {
        OAuth oa = new OAuth();
        authUrl = oa.newAuthorization(service);
        System.debug(authUrl);
        if(authUrl==null) {
            this.message = oa.message;
            return null;
        } else {
            return new PageReference(authUrl);
        }
    }

    public PageReference completeAuthorization() {
        String token = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oauth_token');
        if(token!=null)
        {
            String verifier = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oauth_verifier');
            OAuth oa = new OAuth();
            authSuccess = oa.completeAuthorization(token,verifier);
            this.message = oa.message;
        }
        else {
            message = 'Invalid request. Missing parameter oauth_token';
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**My OAuth class looks like this**

```
global class OAuth {

    private OAuthService__c service;
    private String token;
    private String tokenSecret;
    private Boolean isAccess = false;
    private String verifier;

    private String nonce;
    private String timestamp;
    private String signature;
    private String consumerKey;
    private String consumerSecret;

    private Map<String,String> parameters = new Map<String,String>();

    public String message { get; set; }

    public String callbackUrl {get; set; }

    public void setConsumerKey(String value) { consumerKey = value; }
    public void setConsumerSecret(String value) { consumerSecret = value; }

    /**
     * Looks up service name and starts a new authorization process
     * returns the authorization URL that the user should be redirected to
     * If null is returned, the request failed. The message property will contain
     * the reason.
     */ 
    public String newAuthorization(String serviceName) {

        service = [SELECT request_token_url__c, access_token_url__c, consumer_key__c, 
                          consumer_secret__c, authorization_url__c,
                          (select token__c, secret__c, isAccess__c FROM tokens__r WHERE owner__c=:UserInfo.getUserId() ) 
                          FROM OAuthService__c WHERE name = :serviceName];

        if(service==null) {
            System.debug('Couldn\'t find Oauth Service '+serviceName);
            message = 'Service '+serviceName+' was not found in the local configuration';
            return null;
        }

        if(callbackUrl==null) { 
            if(ApexPages.currentPage()==null || ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')==null) {
                message = 'No callback page was set and it couldn\'t be generated from Apex context';
                System.debug(message);
                return null;
            }

            callbackUrl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('https://'+ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host')+
                                                 Page.CompleteAuth.getUrl(),'UTF-8');
        }

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        //req.setClientCertificateName('Gliffy');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.abc.com/api/1.0/accounts/5/oauth_token.xml?action=create&description=createuser');//service.request_token_url__c
        req.setTimeout(12000);
        System.debug('Request body set to: '+req.getBody());
        consumerKey = service.consumer_key__c;
        consumerSecret = service.consumer_secret__c;
        sign(req);
        HttpResponse res = null;
        if(serviceName=='test1234') {
            // testing
            res = new HttpResponse();
        } else {
            res = h.send(req);
        }
        System.debug('Response from request token request: ('+res.getStatusCode()+')'+res.getBody());
        if(res.getStatusCode()>299) {
            message = 'Failed getting a request token. HTTP Code = '+res.getStatusCode()+
                      '. Message: '+res.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+res.getBody();
            return null;
        }
        String resParams = serviceName == 'test1234' ? 
            'oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=token_secret' : res.getBody();
        Map<String,String> rp = getUrlParams(resParams);
        OAuth_Token__c t = new OAuth_Token__c();
        t.owner__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        t.OAuth_Service__c = service.id;
        t.token__c = rp.get('oauth_token');
        t.secret__c = rp.get('oauth_token_secret');
        t.isAccess__c = false;

        delete service.tokens__r;

        insert t;

        System.debug('Got request token: '+t.token__c+'('+rp.get('oauth_token')+')');

        if(service.authorization_url__c.contains('?')) {
            return service.authorization_url__c+'&oauth_token='+EncodingUtil.urlDecode(t.token__c,'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_key='+service.consumer_key__c;
        } else {
            return service.authorization_url__c+'?oauth_token='+EncodingUtil.urlDecode(t.token__c,'UTF-8')+'&oauth_consumer_key='+service.consumer_key__c;
        }
    }

    public boolean completeAuthorization(String token, String verifier) {
        System.debug('Completing authorization for request token '+token+' with verifier '+verifier);
        OAuth_Token__c t = null;
        try {
            t =
            [SELECT OAuth_Service__r.name, OAuth_Service__r.access_token_url__c, OAuth_Service__r.consumer_key__c, 
             OAuth_Service__r.consumer_secret__c, token__c, secret__c, isAccess__c FROM OAuth_Token__c 
             WHERE owner__c=:UserInfo.getUserId() AND token__c = :EncodingUtil.urlEncode(token,'UTF-8') AND isAccess__c = false];
        } catch(System.QueryException e) {
            message = 'Unknown request token: '+token+'. Restart authorization process';
            System.debug(message);
            return false;

        }

        service = t.Oauth_Service__r;

        consumerKey = service.Consumer_Key__c;
        consumerSecret = service.Consumer_Secret__c;
        this.token = t.token__c;
        tokenSecret = t.secret__c;
        if(verifier!=null) {
            this.verifier = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(verifier,'UTF-8');
        }

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setClientCertificateName('Gliffy');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(service.access_token_url__c);
        req.setBody('');
        sign(req);
        HttpResponse res = null;
        if(service.name=='test1234') {
            res = new HttpResponse();
        } else {
            res = h.send(req);
            System.debug('Response from request token request: ('+res.getStatusCode()+')'+res.getBody());
        }
        if(res.getStatusCode()>299) {
            message = 'Failed getting an access token. HTTP Code = '+res.getStatusCode()+'. Message: '+res.getStatus()+'. Response Body: '+res.getBody();
            return false;
        }

        String resParams = service.name == 'test1234' ? 
            'oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=token_secret' : res.getBody();

        Map<String,String> rp = new Map<String,String>();
        for(String s : resParams.split('&')) {
            List<String> kv = s.split('=');
            rp.put(kv[0],kv[1]);
            System.debug('Access token response param: '+kv[0]+'='+kv[1]);
        }

        t.token__c = rp.get('oauth_token');
        t.secret__c = rp.get('oauth_token_secret');
        t.isAccess__c = true;

        update t;

        return true;
    }

    public List<User> getUsersOfService(String serviceName) {
        List<OAuth_Token__c> l =
            [SELECT OAuth_Service__r.name, isAccess__c, Owner__r.name FROM OAuth_Token__c 
             WHERE OAuth_Service__r.name= :serviceName AND isAccess__c = true];

        List<User> result = new List<User>();
        for(OAuth_Token__c t : l) {
            result.add(t.owner__r);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean setService(String serviceName) {
        return setService(serviceName,UserInfo.getUserId());
    }

    public boolean setService(String serviceName, ID userId) {
        OAuth_Token__c t = null;
        try {
            t =
            [SELECT OAuth_Service__r.name, OAuth_Service__r.consumer_key__c, OAuth_Service__r.consumer_secret__c, 
             token__c, secret__c, isAccess__c FROM OAuth_Token__c 
             WHERE OAuth_Service__r.name= :serviceName AND owner__c=:userId AND isAccess__c = true];
        } catch(System.QueryException e) {
            try {
                // Two-legged OAuth - try to find match on serviceName
                service = [SELECT id, name, consumer_key__c, consumer_secret__c 
                 FROM OAuthService__c 
                 WHERE name= :serviceName];

                System.debug('Preparing Two-legged OAuth request to service '+service.name);

                consumerKey = service.Consumer_Key__c;
                consumerSecret = service.Consumer_Secret__c;
                this.token = '';
                tokenSecret = '';       
                return true;
            } catch(System.QueryException e1) {
                message = 'Couldn\'t find service '+serviceName+'. ['+e1+']';
                System.debug(message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        service = t.Oauth_Service__r;

        System.debug('Preparing OAuth request to service '+service.name);

        consumerKey = service.Consumer_Key__c;
        consumerSecret = service.Consumer_Secret__c;
        this.token = t.token__c;
        tokenSecret = t.secret__c;      
        return true;
    }

    private void refreshParameters() {
        parameters.clear();
        parameters.put('oauth_consumer_key',consumerKey);
        if(token!=null) {
            parameters.put('oauth_token',token);
        }
        if(verifier!=null) {
            parameters.put('oauth_verifier',verifier);
        }
        parameters.put('oauth_signature_method','HMAC-SHA1');
        parameters.put('oauth_timestamp',timestamp);
        parameters.put('oauth_nonce',nonce);
        parameters.put('oauth_callback',callbackUrl);
    }

    private Map<String,String> getUrlParams(String value) {

        Map<String,String> res = new Map<String,String>();
        if(value==null || value=='') {
            return res;
        }
        for(String s : value.split('&')) {
            System.debug('getUrlParams: '+s);
            List<String> kv = s.split('=');
            if(kv.size()>1) {
              // RFC 5849 section 3.4.1.3.1 and 3.4.1.3.2 specify that parameter names 
              // and values are decoded then encoded before being sorted and concatenated
              // Section 3.6 specifies that space must be encoded as %20 and not +
              String encName = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[0], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
              String encValue = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(kv[1], 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8').replace('+','%20');
              System.debug('getUrlParams:  -> '+encName+','+encValue);
              res.put(encName,encValue);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    private String createBaseString(Map<String,String> oauthParams, HttpRequest req) {
        Map<String,String> p = oauthParams.clone();
        if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase('post') && req.getBody()!=null && 
           req.getHeader('Content-Type')=='application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
            p.putAll(getUrlParams(req.getBody()));
        }
        String host = req.getEndpoint();
        Integer n = host.indexOf('?');
        if(n>-1) {
            p.putAll(getUrlParams(host.substring(n+1)));
            host = host.substring(0,n);
        }
        List<String> keys = new List<String>();
        keys.addAll(p.keySet());
        keys.sort();
        String s = keys.get(0)+'='+p.get(keys.get(0));
        for(Integer i=1;i<keys.size();i++) {
            s = s + '&' + keys.get(i)+'='+p.get(keys.get(i));
        }

        // According to OAuth spec, host string should be lowercased, but Google and LinkedIn
        // both expect that case is preserved.
        return req.getMethod().toUpperCase()+ '&' + 
            EncodingUtil.urlEncode(host, 'UTF-8') + '&' +
            EncodingUtil.urlEncode(s, 'UTF-8');
    }

    public void sign(HttpRequest req) {

        nonce = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomLong());
        timestamp = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()/1000);

        refreshParameters();

        String s = createBaseString(parameters, req);

        System.debug('Signature base string: '+s);

        Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(s), 
                       Blob.valueOf(consumerSecret+'&'+
                                    (tokenSecret!=null ? tokenSecret : '')));
        signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');
        System.debug('Signature: '+signature);

        String header = 'OAuth ';
        for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
            header = header + key + '="'+parameters.get(key)+'", ';
        }
        header = header + 'oauth_signature="'+signature+'"';
        System.debug('Authorization: '+header);
        req.setHeader('Authorization',header);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Inside your authorize method second line referring service which is not initialized anywhere which is causing this issue. Assign some value to that variable and it will resolve your issue

Comment: @Himanshu Thanks for the answer, I think We get null object error only when we don't have value for varialble.I think we get this error because we don't have token value?

Comment: enable the debug mode and check at which line you are getting this error. it will help you to get exact line no.